# Full width CSS with 2 column, fixed menu width and dynamic content width

Tags: html, css

I have problem with fixing this issue. I am not using bootstrap, cos i started without bootstrap (and not sure if bootstrap can do this).
I have a full width layout with a fixed menu width. Then my content area should be dynamic because I want it to be responsive.

http://send2list.com/help/troubleshoot.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="da-DK">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#e0e0e0;color:#fff;margin:0px;">

  <div style="width:100%;">
      <div style="background-color:#000;">
        <div style="float:left;background-color:#222223;width:900px;">Content Area<br> Content width should be responsive. Right now it is set to width 900px. But if user were to resize screen, it should be smaller. Any way to do this with just CSS?</div>
        <div style="float:right;background-color:#499939;">Right Menu<br>Right menu is fixed with 240px</div>

      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this can be done with CSS by setting the `div`s to `display: table-cell` (`display: table-cell` is fully supported) instead of `float: left`. The first `div` is a percentage and the second is a fixed width. The container needs to be set to `display: table` and `table-layout: fixed` in order to enforce the fixed width:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">Content Area<br/> Content width should be responsive. Right now it is set to width 900px. But if user were to resize screen, it should be smaller. Any way to do this with just CSS?</div>
  <div class="two">Right Menu<br/>Right menu is fixed with 240px</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.one{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*width: 85%;*/ //REMOVE as VitorinoFernandes pointed out, this is not necesssary seeing how setting the div to display: table-cell within a container set to "display: table" will take the remaining width
  background: #222223;
}

.two{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 240px;
  background: #499939;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LxLs1bk/1/)

Comment: @SathishS you misunderstood the question. OP wants the second `div` to have a fixed width of 240px. If the intent was to have them be different sizes `float` would more than suffice

Comment: its takes the only 85% of the screen its cover

Comment: no need for giving % value it will take the space available

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using calc to set the main area to 100% - 240px. Calc support is good as long as you don't need to support IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxrw3dmq/)

```
.main {
    float:left;
    background-color:#222223;
    width: calc(100% - 240px);
}
.sidebar {
    float:right;
    background-color:#499939;
    width: 240px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i didn't know about the calc function.